# Excel VBA Combo Box List

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to set the values available in a combo box list to show a list of years from 2010 to the current year. So now it would 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013 and 2014. Next year it would show 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014 and 2015. In 2016 it would show 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 and 2016.

Currently when the workbook is opened the values as set using the following. How can I code it so that it builds the list from 2010 to the current year?

```
With Sheet1.YearCombo
     .AddItem "2012"
     .AddItem "2013"
     .AddItem "2014"
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

use Year() and Date() to get the current year and then loop to add the items

```
CurrentYear = Year(Date)

With Sheet1.YearCombo
     .clear
    For yr = 2010 To CurrentYear
        .AddItem yr
    Next yr
End With
```

Comment: maybe add a `.clear` before the loop, or you'll geta big list soon, xwith the same values